# DocumentRoot in .htaccess is causing an error

Tags: apache, configuration

I have  DocumentRoot /var/www/test    in my .htaccess file. This is causing the apache server to give me a 500 internal server error.

The error log file shows:
alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/.htaccess: DocumentRoot not allowed here

AllowOveride All is set in my conf file.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive cannot appear in a `.htaccess` file. Put it in `httpd.conf` instead.

Comment: or a specified VirtualHost file

Comment: This is what happens when you stay up in the early hours of the morning (uk time here) working on technical problems. You get sloppy. Thanks for the kick up the arse.

Comment: what if i don't have access to `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhost.conf` and still want to specify the document root? thanks

Comment: @black sensei: The DocumentRoot is used by apache to *find* the `.htaccess` file. You will probably need to talk to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

DocumentRoot should be set in your VirtualHost directive, not your .htaccess file.

Any specific reason you put DocumentRoot in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your apache version , but docs for 2.0 say that DocumentRoot is only valid for virtualhost or server config. Acording to the docs it should not be used in a .htacces

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot